# My Heroku-cli not recognizing commands. (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

When I run $"heroku help" in my Mac OS X Terminal, I get the following error from the Heroku Cli.

```
$ heroku help
 ▸    help is not a heroku command.
 ▸    Perhaps you meant help
 ▸    Run heroku help for a list of available commands.
```

And it applies to every heroku command except "heroku login".

```
$ heroku restart
 ▸    restart is not a heroku command.
 ▸    Perhaps you meant restart
 ▸    Run heroku help for a list of available commands.
```

etc...

Is anyone else experiencing the same problem? Or how do I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue (OSX) and was able to fix it. Here's what I did.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#troubleshooting

That link has some trouble shooting help. It referenced a log file so I went there.

```
cat ~/Library/Caches/heroku/error.log
```

Nothing obviously wrong for me, just references to "...is not a command", but the stack traces called out the following path.

```
/Users/[username]/.local/share/heroku/
```

I deleted that folder and did another reinstall of heroku.
Everything started working for me.

One thing I noticed was that although I had ungraded heroku and it said it was installing a new version, running the following command still declared the previous version I had installed.

```
heroku --version
```

so it sounds like it's a caching issue.